# Limit text length and putting read more button

Tags: php

I want to put a read more button at the end of a content block and limit the length of the content block to 200 characters. This is my code

```
 <?php echo $row["newscontent"] ?>
```

How can I limit $row["newscontent"] to 200 characters?

Comment: Edited question to show embedded code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the length of $row['newscontent'] with the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function

```
echo substr($row['newscontent'], 0, 199);
```

There are various hang-ups that you should be aware of though: it will take 200 characters, it doesn't handle multibyte strings well (utf-8 etc) and if your newscontent contains markup, it will likely be broken

Comment: Yeah. I have already applied it to my code and it works. Can you help me in putting link to the read more button?

Answer (score 0):

Try below,

```
for($i=0; $i<=200; $i++){ echo $row['newscontent'][$i];}
echo "...Read More..";
```

you can append any other thing you want to, like the link to the full content.