# Show More button hide button if all are displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the show more button to show my listing, but I want to hide the show more button if all listing is displayed but that doesn't work

```
[https://codepen.io/dreadkopp/pen/VjeKee][1]
```

I'm using the script from this example which is working as per my requirement.

Comment: It might be similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828729/limit-text-length-and-putting-read-more-button

Comment: @Drake95 The one you link is PHP tagged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a selector to the more button in HTML

```
<button id="more" onclick="showmore()">show more</button> // added id="more"
```

Then, while showMore and showLess, check for visible blocks and handle the toggle more button with the `toggleMore` method as shown below:

```js
//show 4 elements at beginning
var nblock = 3;
//how much elements should be added/removed
var add_remove = 4;

$(".referenceblock:gt(" + nblock + ")").hide();


function toggleMore() { //ADDED THIS METHOD
  if (!$(".referenceblock:hidden").length) {
     $("#more").hide();
  } else {
    $("#more").show();
  }
}

function showmore() {

  if ((nblock+1) < $('.referenceblock').length)
    nblock = nblock + add_remove;

  $(".referenceblock").fadeIn();
  $(".referenceblock:gt(" + nblock + ")").hide();
  toggleMore(); // CALLING HERE 
};

function showless() {

  if (nblock > add_remove) {
    nblock = nblock - add_remove;
  }

  $(".referenceblock:gt(" + nblock + ")").fadeOut(400, toggleMore); // AND HERE
};
```

```css
.referenceblock {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="referenceblock">
    <img src="http://hys2d3ayt6x6b7ts22ypg68p.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vinyl-record.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
  </div>
  <button id="more" onclick="showmore()">show more</button>
  <button onclick="showless()">show less</button>
</div>
```